# keep getting exception, value not getting input into array

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

Here is my code.. I'm trying to read in from a file with comma delimited data and the names are in the file as `"Doe,John"` so I am using this to get the name, without it being seperated out by the comma....

```
fileIn = new TextFieldParser(INPUT_FILE_NAME);
    fileIn.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    fileIn.SetDelimiters(",");
    fileIn.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
```

Here is some of my source code. The name is not being put into `nameArray[i] = words[1];`

```
static void InputEmployeeData()
{
  int i;
  string[] words;

  numOfEmployee = Int32.Parse(fileIn.ReadLine());
  idArray = new int[numOfEmployee];
  nameArray = new string[numOfEmployee];
  deptArray = new int[numOfEmployee];
  payrateArray = new double[numOfEmployee];
  hoursArray = new double[numOfEmployee];
  for (i = 0; i <= numOfEmployee; i++)
  {
    words = fileIn.ReadFields();
    idArray[i] = Int32.Parse(words[0]);
    nameArray[i] = words[1];
    deptArray[i] = Int32.Parse(words[2]);
    payrateArray[i] = Double.Parse(words[3]);
    hoursArray[i] = Double.Parse(words[4]);
  }
}
```

A sample line from the data file I am reading in from is this.

`0090,"Baker, John",1,32.57,50.75`

I have `numOfEmployee = readline` because there is metadata at the top of the file to let me know how many persons are in the file. I keep getting an exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) on line 86....

`idArray[i] = int.Parse(words[0]);`

Comment: have you tried fileIn.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," }); ?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you really need to use a class `Employee` here and a `List<Employee>`

Comment: where at exactly?

Comment: agreed steve, we just haven't made it that far in class.

Comment: Can't you just analyze your code using debugger? Step-by-step you will find what is going on...Is ReadFields returning null?

Comment: i have and i've noticed it doesn't read in the name, it's like i get that exception on line 86.. but it's reading in the ID, and after it runs the line for inputting the name, it doesn't put anything into nameArray.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this line

```
for (i = 0; i <= numOfEmployee; i++)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < numOfEmployee; i++)
```

The for loop cycles to many times because it start from zero so, you should stop at `numOfEmployee - 1`. If you execute the loop as is, in the last loop the `words` array is set to null by the `TextFieldParser.ReadFields` and you get the Object Reference Not Set Exception